# Is type of unsigned short + int implementation-defined?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given this code,

```
unsigned short us = 0; 
int i = 0;
auto sum = us + i;
```

is the type of `sum` implementation-defined? My reading of the C++11 standard says yes:

- 5.7/1 says that the usual arithmetic conversions are applied.
- 4.13/1 bullets 2 and 3 say that the rank of int is greater than the rank of unsigned short.
- 5/9 bullet 5 subbullet 4 says that if int can represent all values in unsigned short, the unsigned short is converted to int, and the type of `sum` is int.
- 5/9 bullet 5 subbullet 5 says that if int can't represent all the values in unsigned short, both operands are converted to unsigned int, and the type of `sum` is unsigned int.

If the above analysis is legitimate, it means that using `auto` to declare variables initialized with arithmetic expressions on built-in types can lead to implementation-defined results. I'm guessing it would surprise a lot of programmers that the type of `sum` above is not fully determined by the standard.

Is my reasoning legitimate?

Comment: Well, it's sort of "fully determined" after you consult your platform's type characteristics...

Comment: Which means it's not fully determined by the standard :-)

Comment: To put it another way, if it *were* fully determined by the standard, then you could just throw out the entire section on arithmetic conversions and replace it by a simple matrix that tells you the actual result types. Your `sum` has type `std::common_type<unsigned short, int>::type`, for what it's worth...

Comment: I think (though I don't know) it _must_ be implementation-defined, because `int` could be the same size as `short`. It usually isn't, but it is allowed to be. Which means that although it usually does, a signed `int` _might not_ be able to hold all values of an unsigned `short`. So, there really can't be a single well-defined type.

Comment: @Kerrek: Are you sure the type of `sum` is the result of your `std::common_type` expression?  My reading of the spec for `common_type` is that it's platform-independent, and in the case we're dealing with, it would unconditionally return `int` (because `unsigned short` can be converted to `int`).

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: I think so... `common_type` is the type of `true ? a : b`, which I think calls for the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @Kerrek: Ah, it looks like you're right, per 5.16/6 bullet 2, though I didn't read the full spec for `?:`, so I may have overlooked something.

Comment: The type is implementation-specific, but not implementation-defined. Implementation-defined means that the implementation must document what it does.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's a great statement. You should make that an answer.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `auto`. The expression `us + i` has an implementation-specific type. Instead of avoiding `auto`, you should avoid mixing signed and unsigned types in arithmetic operations.

Comment: "auto" is going to be causing headaches for a while, they're trying to alleviate some in C++1y, See [Here comes decltype(auto)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is implementation-specific, but not implementation-defined. Implementation-defined means that the implementation must document what it does.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, but I encourage readers to check the comments on the original question for additional information.

Comment: The Standard's specs for Impleentation-Defined behavior are rather vague as to the form any required documentation must take, and how specific it must be.  An implementation which specifies the ranges of `int` and `unsigned short` (as required by the Standard) will in so doing indicate how operations involving those types must behave.